# YA science fiction novel with title starting with the word "Uncle" (I thought)

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Sometime in the 1990s I read reviews and saw copies of a YA science fiction novel whose title was "Uncle " - the name of the uncle was unusual (a word not usually considered a name).  The only characteristics of the book I can remember are that it was about an unusual family with powers, possibly including interdimensional travel.  The uncle was possibly a villain, or at least a dangerous character.  It's the kind of book that William Sleator would have written (it's possible I'm confusing some of the details with Sleator's [Others See Us](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-525-45104-4)).  The uncle's name was probably 5 or 6 letters long, possibly starting with a 'P'.

Comment: Is it one of these? (I ran an ISFDB search for "Uncle P.")
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=uncle+p&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: https://www.bookfinder.com/search/?author=&title=Uncle&lang=en&new_used=*&destination=us&currency=USD&binding=*&isbn=&keywords=&minprice=&maxprice=&publisher=&min_year=1990&max_year=1999&mode=advanced&st=sr&ac=qr

Comment: *Uncle Terrible*? http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13965

Comment: No luck so far, but thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. I found the book - in spite of being completely wrong about most of the details above.

It's *[Panda Ray](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?317)* by Michael Kandel - reviewed in Asimovs twice, in 1996 and 1997.  It does feature a boy fleeing his dangerous family, but while the fellow who helps him might be avuncular, he's not an uncle.

It's reviewed [here](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/michael-kandel/panda-ray/)

> In western Pennsylvania live the Zimmerman family: Aliens, or mutants
> from the future, who possess strange powers and devices—they conceal
> themselves by controlling key figures in the community. But when
> ten-year-old Christopher starts boasting of his exploits at school,
> Mother decides that he must be scooped out- -permanently deprived of
> his magic/psi powers and turned into an ordinary straight-A student
> and model citizen . . . just like his brother, Brian. In desperation,
> Christopher flees to Gramps, who similarly is resisting being banished
> to a retirement home in Florida. Together, the pair go journeying
> through space, time, and probability—but Mother still pursues them
> with relentless fanaticism. There's one chance, Gramps thinks: His old
> friend and mentor, Panda Ray, will be able to help them, but
> Christopher will end up as an entirely different person.

Comment: Once this has been here 24 hours, you can accept your self-answer.

Comment: Will do - thanks